# Check what type of Temporal a given format string can be used to parse

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

I'm given some datetime format string that user entered, and need to check into what `java.time` temporals I can parse data in that format (within reason, I indend to support only the simpler cases for now).

Something along the lines of this table:

| Input Format | Expected Answer |
| --- | --- |
| `yyyy-MM` | `java.time.YearMonth` |
| `MM/dd/yyyy` | `java.time.LocalDate` |
| `yyyy:DD` | `java.time.LocalDate` (because of day-of-year data) |
| `HH:mm:ss` | `java.time.LocalTime` |
| `dd MM yyyy hh:mm:ssV` | `java.time.ZonedDateTime` |

Keeping in mind, that both the date format and the date are entered by the user, so these input formats are just examples, and they obviously can contain literals (but not optional parts, that's a relief).

So far I've only been able to come up with this tornado of `if`s as a solution:

```
private static final ZonedDateTime ZDT = ZonedDateTime.of(1990, 10, 26, 14, 40, 59, 123456, ZoneId.of("Europe/Oslo"));
...
String formatted = externalFormatter.format(ZDT);
Class<?> type;
TemporalAccessor parsed = externalFormatter.parse(formatted);
if (parsed.isSupported(YEAR)) {
    if (parsed.isSupported(MONTH_OF_YEAR)) {
        if (parsed.query(TemporalQueries.localDate()) != null) {
            if (parsed.query(TemporalQueries.localTime()) != null) {
                if (parsed.query(TemporalQueries.zone()) != null) {
                    type = ZonedDateTime.class;
                }
                else if (parsed.query(TemporalQueries.offset()) != null) {
                    type = OffsetDateTime.class;
                }
                else {
                    type = LocalDateTime.class;
                }
            }
            else {
                type = LocalDate.class;
            }
        }
        else {
            type = YearMonth.class;
        }
    }
    else {
        type = Year.class;
    }
}
else if (parsed.query(TemporalQueries.localTime()) != null) {
    if (parsed.query(TemporalQueries.offset()) != null) {
       type = OffsetTime.class;
    }
    else {
        type = LocalTime.class;
    }
}
```

Surely, there must be some better way, at least marginally? I will not limit myself to just using `java.time`, I also have the Joda-Time library available to me (although it's technically on legacy status), and I will not turn down a simpler code that uses the `SimpleDateFormat` if there is such an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### DateTimeFormatter::parseBest()

I am taking your word for it:

> Keeping in mind, that both the date format and the date are entered by
> the user, …

So I am assuming that I may use both the format pattern and the date string entered for seeing what I can make of it. `DateTimeFormatter::parseBest()` is the method we need for that.

```
public static TemporalAccessor parse(String formatPattern, String toBeParsed) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(formatPattern, Locale.ROOT);
    return formatter.parseBest(toBeParsed, ZonedDateTime::from,
            LocalDate::from, LocalTime::from, YearMonth::from);
}
```

For demonstrating the power of the above method I am using the following auxiliary method:

```
public static void demo(String formatPattern, String toBeParsed) {
    TemporalAccessor result = parse(formatPattern, toBeParsed);
    System.out.format("%-21s %s%n", formatPattern, result.getClass().getName());
}
```

Let’s call it using your examples:

```
    demo("yyyy-MM", "2017-11");
    demo("MM/dd/yyyy", "10/21/2023");
    demo("yyyy:DD", "2021:303");
    demo("HH:mm:ss", "23:34:45");
    demo("dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ssVV", "05 09 2023 14:01:55Europe/Oslo");
```

I have corrected a couple of errors in the last format pattern string. Output is:

> ```
> yyyy-MM               java.time.YearMonth
> MM/dd/yyyy            java.time.LocalDate
> yyyy:DD               java.time.LocalDate
> HH:mm:ss              java.time.LocalTime
> dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ssVV java.time.ZonedDateTime
> ```

In the list of `TemporalQuery` arguments to `parseBest()` it’s essential to put the classes that hold the most information first. Or which classes you prefer, but I assumed you wanted as much information as you can have. `parseBest()` uses the *first* query that works. So put `ZonedDateTime` first and `Year`, `Month` and `DayOfWeek` last if you intend to support any of the last three.

Remember to decide which locale you want.

### With only the format pattern string

If you are supposed to do the trick without the string to be parsed, it’s not badly more complicated. Start by *formatting* some `ZonedDateTime` using the formatter that you have constructed from the format pattern string. Then use `parseBest()` to parse the resulting string back. You must use `ZonedDateTime` because it’s the only class that holds about every field that could thinkably be in the format pattern string, so with some other class, formatting could break. On the other hand the information coming into the formatted string is limited by the pattern, so in most cases you won’t be able to parse a `ZonedDateTime` back. Which is exactly what we want: `parseBest()` will tell us which class we *can* parse into.

```
public static Class<? extends TemporalAccessor> getParseableType(String formatPattern) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(formatPattern, Locale.ROOT);
    String example = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(formatter);
    TemporalAccessor parseableTemporalAccessor = formatter.parseBest(example, ZonedDateTime::from,
            LocalDate::from, LocalTime::from, YearMonth::from);
    return parseableTemporalAccessor.getClass();
}
```

### Documentation link

[`parseBest​(CharSequence text, TemporalQuery<?>... queries)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseBest(java.lang.CharSequence,java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery...))

Comment: nice! I needed that a few times and did not know it existed.

Comment: So technically, the solution would be a kind of what I already did (i.e. having a ZDT instance and parsing it in various ways), but using the `T::from` refs instead of manually rolled code. I do admit that `parseBest` produces a cleaner code than what I have, though it's a touch unfortunate that `parseBest` relies on exception trapping for flow control (admittedly, there's not really a version of `from` that doesn't throw). I'm going to give it couple of more days on the chance that someone has other (better) suggestions, and then accept this as an answer.

Comment: I understand your hesitation. I admit I wasn’t thinking about the fact that `parseBest()` works by exceptions, but you’re right, it needs to, and inspecting the source code confirms that it does. I would still consider this a case of “hiding an ugly implementation behind a nice interface”, which is sometimes the best way forward.